# How to retrieve multiple images from one image handler?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I've seen some other questions similar to mine, but I didn't quite see how I could use that to fix my code.  I have a webform with a dropdown list which is used to select the picture you want.  My problem is that right now I'm using multiple image handlers for each image.  here are examples of the code:

the webform:

```
namespace MultiCameraPage
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void SelBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;


        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
                Response.Redirect("Page1.htm");
                break;
            case 1:
                Response.Redirect("Page2.htm");
                break;
            case 2:
                Response.Redirect("Page3.htm");
                break;
            case 3:
                Response.Redirect("Page4.htm");
                break;

        }

    }

}
}
```

it just redirects to the webpage that has the picture you want.  I'll show "page1" and "page2" and the rest is just the say with names changed.

page1 html:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function refreshIt() {
        if (!document.images) return;
        document.getElementById("imgcontainer1").src = "/Page1Handler.ashx?" + Math.random();
        setTimeout('refreshIt()', 700);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload=" setTimeout('refreshIt()',700)">
<img id="imgcontainer1" src="/Page1Handler.ashx" alt="cam image1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Page1Handler:

This handler has to save the picture from a filestream

```
namespace MultiCameraPage
{

public class Page1Handler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string saveTo = @"C:pathtoImage\images\XIG.jpg";
        FileStream writeStream1 = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        using (FileStream fs1 = File.Open(@"C:\Path to filestream", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            ReadWriteStream1(fs1, writeStream1);
        }
        byte[] tt = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/XIG.jpg"));
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream1(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Page2 html:

it's the same as page1 just with names changed

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function refreshIt() {
        if (!document.images) return;
        document.getElementById("imgcontainer2").src = "/Page2.ashx?" + Math.random();
        setTimeout('refreshIt()', 700);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload=" setTimeout('refreshIt()',700)">
<img id="imgcontainer2" src="/Page2.ashx" alt="cam image2"/>
</body>
```

Page2.ashx:

The same as page1Handler.ashx

```
namespace MultiCameraPage
{

public class Page2 : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string saveTo = @"C:\PathToImage\images\GateV.jpg";
        FileStream writeStream3 = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        using (FileStream fs3 = File.Open(@"C:\path to filestream", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            ReadWriteStream3(fs3, writeStream3);
        }
        byte[] tt = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/GateV.jpg"));
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream3(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
}
```

The rest is just these files repeated.
I feel like this is the worst way to do this and that is why I'm asking for help.  The dropdown menu is attached to a datatable that only has the name of the picture and nothing else.  Should I add something else to the datatable?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should be able to use one handler and pass image name as a parameter to it. So you image tags will look like:

```
<img id="imgcontainer2" src="/ImageHandler.ashx?imageName=GateV.jpg" alt="cam image2"/>
```

And the handler itself just decides what image to load reading this parameter:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string imageName = context.Request["imageName"]; //make sure to handle case when this param is missing

    string saveTo = string.Format(@"C:pathtoImage\images\{0}", imageName);
    ...
```

Comment: what library do I include to use "Request"?  I can't find which one.

Comment: @user3634308, apologies, this is a property of the HttpContext. Post updated